# php html table remove one data

Tags: php, html

i have problem with my table inside my table. it removes the last data in the second table.

the first table gives the correct output but the second table gives the wrong output. the second table can be shown by clicking the table row. the table row is expandable.

this is my code

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <?php
                require_once 'dbconfig.php';
                try {
                    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname",
                            $username, $password);
                    $stmt1 = $conn->prepare("select * from table where name=?");
                        $stmt1->bindParam(1, $_temppp1, PDO::PARAM_STR, 30); 
                        $stmt1->execute();
                } catch (PDOException $pe) {
                    die("Error occurred:" . $pe->getMessage());
                }
                ?>                  
                <table id="report" class="table table-bordered ">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                    <th>Track Number</th>
                    <th>Document Title</th>
                    <th>Document Type</th>
                    <th>Date Filled</th>
                    <th> </th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <?php while ($row1 = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)): ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $row1['tracknum']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row1['doctitle']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row1['doctype']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row1['datefilled']; ?></td>
                             <td>
                             <div class="arrow"><a id="menu-toggle" href="#" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i></a></div>



                             </td>

                        </tr>
                        <tr><td colspan="5">
                        <table class="table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Row</th>
                                    <th>First Name</th>
                                    <th>Last Name</th>
                                    <th>Email</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>1</td>
                                    <td>John</td>
                                    <td>Carter</td>
                                    <td>johncarter@mail.com</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>2</td>
                                    <td>Peter</td>
                                    <td>Parker</td>
                                    <td>peterparker@mail.com</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>3</td>
                                    <td>John</td>
                                    <td>Rambo</td>
                                    <td>johnrambo@mail.com</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>

                        </td>
                        </tr>



                        </td>
                        </tr>
                <?php endwhile; ?>

                </table> 

                </div>
```

and this is the output [image]

Comment: View the page source in your browser

Comment: why? can i found the problem there?

Comment: Is there any css rules on the page? Could be restrictions the height of the row.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong i think

change this

```
                </td>
                </tr>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

        </table> 

        </div>
```

to that

```
        <?php endwhile; ?>
                </td>
                </tr>
        </table> 

        </div>
```

and try again  or loock in this region..

Comment: it's still the same. i've been looking for the problem but i can't find it

Comment: Your code works fine on my db. so look what is in the db, or as sugested look at the generated code.

Comment: Looking at my generated code I would remove:  <div class="arrow"><a id="menu-toggle" href="#" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i></a></div> and have a try.Then check the db entries for characters like < >. Maybe that helps

Comment: my database only accepts string. i also tried you're latest suggestion but it doesn't work. the output is still the same. the html source code is the same on my php file. but it hides the last column. weird